# How to cout the value of a string variable stored in another string variable

Tags: c++

I'm new to c++. I'm trying to change the color of some text based on what is read in from a config file.

The config file contains:

> RED=DEFCOLOR

RED is defined in a header file:

```
static const std::string RED="\x1b[31m";
```

The code snippet in main()

```
while( std::getline(cfgin, cfgline)) {
    std::stringstream stream(cfgline);
    if( cfgline.find("DEFCOLOR") != string::npos) {
        std::stringstream stream(cfgline);
        getline(stream, DEFCOLOR, '=');
    }
}
```

**DEFCOLOR** now contains the text: RED.

Is there a way to actually use **DEFCOLOR** directly as if it were the value of RED defined in the header file so that executing:

```
cout << DEFCOLOR << "\n";
```

would be the equivalent of:

```
cout << RED << "\n";
```

which actually works? The former currently prints out the text: RED .
I can get it to work by using a series of if statements to check the color:

```
if( DEFCOLOR == "RED") 
{
    cout << RED << "\n";
}
```

but there must be an better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a map:

```
#include <map>

static const std::map<std::string, std::string> colors = {
    { "RED", "\x1b[31m" },
    { "BLUE", "..." },
    { "GREEN", "..." }
};
```

Then:

```
std::cout << colors[DEFCOLOR] << "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks Max! That worked well.